# MongoDB $set to update subarray, adding new entry instead of updating

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ecmascript-6

im trying to update an oject in a sub-array and instead of replacing and updating the data. it adds a new enetry.

controller.js:

```
const updateSubCategory = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const {
    dataArray
  } = req.body

  const categories = await Category.find({})

  if (categories) {
    await Category.updateOne({
      "SubCats._id": req.params.id
    }, {
      "$set": {
        SubCats: {
          name: dataArray[0],
          image: dataArray[1]
        }
      }
    }, {
      "multi": true
    })
    res.json({
      message: 'sub-category updated'
    })
  } else {
    res.status(404)
    throw new Error('Error')
  }
})
```

Comment: Instead of `throw new Error('Error')` you should throw a proper, more descriptive error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this, but i am not sure, if you dont need this, if you can give sample data and expected output in json.

You can try an example [PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=622c99a96f902a4b4b2e75f2)
It updates the fields inside not replace all the embeded document (your query does that).

```js
const updateSubCategory = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const {
    dataArray
  } = req.body

  const categories = await Category.find({})

  if (categories) {
    await Category.updateOne({
      "SubCats._id": req.params.id
    }, {
      "$set": {
        "SubCats.name" : dataArray[0],
        "SubCats.image" : dataArray[1]
        }
      }
    }, {
      "multi": true
    })
    res.json({
      message: 'sub-category updated'
    })
  } else {
    res.status(404)
    throw new Error('Error')
  }
})
```